# C++/CLI - intercepting methods that return a native object

Tags: casting, c++-cli, marshalling

Stack Overflow

Hi,

I'm writing a C# application to sniff the network traffic for an application written with Qt. As best as I can tell,the target application uses:

class QByteArray _*thiscall QIODevice::read(*_int64)

to read the data. My C# application uses the EasyHook library to intercept any calls to QIODevice::read(), and then passes the parameters off to a C++/CLI object that tries to call the native method. The native method returns a QByteArray, and I pass this back to C#, which passes it back to the target application.

In summary:

Target App => Easyhook/C# => C++/CLI => Native Method => C++/CLI => Easyhook/C# => Target App

The architecture seems to work perfectly EXCEPT when the return type of the intercepted method is a native object (such as a QByteArray above).

My C# code looks like this:

```
    // //////////////////////////////////
    // public: class QByteArray __thiscall QIODevice::read(__int64)
    // //////////////////////////////////
    [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.ThisCall, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
    delegate IntPtr DDeviceRead(IntPtr Device, Int64 maxSize);

    // Intercept all calls to Device::Read()
    public IntPtr DeviceRead_Intercepted(IntPtr Device, Int64 maxSize)
    {
        // Call the method from C++/CLI
        IODeviceWrapper qtDevice = new IODeviceWrapper(Device);
        return qtDevice.Read(maxSize);
    }
```

And my C++/CLI code looks like this:

```
IntPtr IODeviceWrapper::Read(Int64 maxSize)
{
    QByteArray * retArray = &Native->read(maxSize);
    return static_cast<IntPtr>(retArray);
}
```

C++ isn't my favoured language - so things like pointers and references to objects can be a little confusing at times. I've tried a whole lot of variations, but can't seem to make sense of it.

The native Qt read() function I assume returns the address of a newly allocated QByteArray, which the variable accepts, so my C++/CLI code needs to pass that address all the way along the chain back to the target app.

How is this done?

Comment: What is the question exactly? Is it compiled? Does it work?

Comment: The question is how I go about passing the QByteArray back up the chain. The C++/CLI code above tries to force it into an IntPtr before it gets passed back to C#.

The code above compiles and runs, but crashes, presumably when the target application receives an object that isn't a QByteArray.

I've successfully returned simple types, as well as pointers to Qt native types (that is, if the QIODevice::read() method returned a POINTER to a QByteArray, there would be no problem).

Do I try to use IntPtrs? Do I use Int32/64? Is there any Marshaling trick?

Comment: I think you need to copy unmanaged QByteArray content to managed byte[] array directly in the Read function, and return this array to the caller. I am not familiar with QByteArray but it must provide access to individual elements and possibly to the whole array through the pointer.

Comment: You can use one on Marshal.Copy overloads for this.

Comment: I think you're assuming that a QByteArray is equivalent to the simple byte[]. What if I was returning a "QGreenMonster" instead? Sure, I could inspect each element of the QByteArray and send back that data, but the target application is expecting an object of type QByteArray.

I am guessing the native QIODevice::read() method allocates memory for the QByteArray and returns the address of that object. I'm currently holding a pointer to that object in "retArray". I want to know how to pass that object back to C#, and then back to the target application.

Comment: OK, I see. Maybe the problem is in QByteArray life cycle? You need to ensure that this object remains alive and not recycled by QT. I don't remember QT details, but try to investigate in this direction.